# How can I uninstall background package or remove text from page

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I installed `background` package and there is text "Draft" all the page

[image]

How can I remove this text or uninstall this package?

Comment: What do you mean with "installed"? Can't you just remove `\usepackage{...}?`

Comment: `\backgroundsetup{contents={}}` will remove the default `contents=Draft`. However, you **will** need some `contents={...}` otherwise the `background` package is pretty useless. It's stated in the manual on the *2nd* page ;-)

Comment: As Manuel say, we probably need to know a bout more about your document before we can advise/help you

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner  I want to remove`\usepackage{background}`. my document looks like http://imgur.com/a/NDxcp

Comment: And why don't you remove `\usepackage{background}`? Just open the file in an editor, remove line 6 and 27, save it and do one or more LaTeX run. Shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I tried it. just remove the line  but there is an error [message](http://imgur.com/a/qACEL)

Comment: Two lines! If you remove the package you also have to remove all commands, defined by the package. Sometimes you also have to remove the auxiliary files, i.e, the `aux`-file. But often you don't need to remove the `aux`-file. Just ignore the error after the first run and do another LaTeX run is often enough.

Comment: @vito: Remove the `.aux` file -- it has some statements from `background` package left over after the removal of `\usepackage{background}`. Recompiling fixes the issue then.

Answer (score 2):

The word `Draft` in magenta colour is the default content for the `background` package.

It can either be removed with `\usepackage[contents={}]{background` or similarly somewhere in the document with `\backgroundsetup{contents={}}`.

However, using `background` without `contents` is pretty useless.

You see, there's no need to uninstall the package. Remove it from the document by omitting `\usepackage{background}`... as usual, but this will leave some lines defined by `background` package in the `.aux` file.
Remove the `.aux` file as well to start from a fresh state and recompile.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{background}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext[3]
\clearpage
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}

\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. `\backgroundsetup{contents={}}` works perfectly  :)